# How Can I forward traffic to the websites IP to the websites domain? (Bitnami/AWS)

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, bitnami

For example, someone goes to http://192.168.1.1 and I want them to be forwarded instantly to https://example.com.

I have a bitnami WordPress instance and you can access it via the IP AND domain name. I have edited the wp-config.php commenting out

```
//define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
//define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' );
```

and added

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://example.com/');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://example.com/');
```

BUT you can still access and use the site via the IP address. I want it so if someone accesses the site via the IP it redirects them to the https://example.com

I have tried to edit the .htaccess BUT any changes get instantly removed upon upload.

Answer (score 3):

Bitnami Engineer here,

To redirect all the requests to your domain and HTTPS, follow the steps below:

- Add the following configuration into the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf file. Remember to replace example.com with your own domain:

```
  <VirtualHost _default_:80>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
    ...
```

- Add the following configuration into the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf file. Remember to replace example.com with your own domain:

```
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
    ...
```

- Add the following configuration into any virtual host file located in the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/vhosts/ directory. Remember to replace example.com with your own domain:

```
  <VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:PORT _default_:PORT>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
    ...
```

- Restart Apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You can get more information here: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/wordpress/administration/use-single-domain/

Comment: I spent many hours in redirecting non-www to www domain in my aws lightsail bitnami instance but noting worked except your method 
NOTE - GUYS dont miss the 3rd step "Add the following configuration into any virtual host file"